# "Invalid Column Name" even though the column is created?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table :

```
create table Praktikant(
    Pr_id char not null Primary key,
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    Mbiemri varchar(100) not null,
    Gender char(1) not null,
    Degree varchar(100) not null,
    age int,
    check (age >18),
    foreign key (Pr_id) references Doctor(Dr_id) on update cascade
)
```

Inserts:

```
insert into Praktikant values ('1', 'Kastriot', 'Tusha', 'M', 'Student', 19);
insert into Praktikant values ('2', 'Trim', 'Dalipi', 'M', 'Student', 23);
insert into Praktikant values ('3', 'Elira', 'Rrmoku', 'F', 'Studente', 24);
insert into Praktikant values ('4', 'Qendresa', 'Krasniqi', 'F', 'Studente',20);
```

Query:

```
    select age
    from Praktikant
    where age > 23
```

I don't understand why I get this message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'age'.
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Can't duplicate using the data provided (fixed the typos in the column names). Are you sure this is the same script and that the columns were created properly?

Comment: Probably the schema, or you're in the wrong DB context.  Are you using default schema `.dbo` or a user schema or something else?  Add it to the table name in all places, ie. `dbo.Praktikant`

Comment: Have int as data type for the pr_id column!

Comment: I would recommend against storing the age of a person. As soon as it hits your database the information is stale. You should instead store their birthdate and calculate age when you need it.

Comment: @JacobH I have writen the code in my native language but translated it for you understand. And all the typos have a uppercase first letter.

Comment: Are the column names different in your language? Do they have special characters (unicode)?

Comment: please check schema name like `dbo.Praktikant`

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly. No errors at all (after removing foreign key to Doctor). I think there is something missing in your explanation of the issue.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!!  Which one is this???

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to get table info:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Praktikant'
```

then find your table schema because i suspect that you have two tables with the same name in another schema.
after find schema use this query for select info:

```
    select age
      from [schema_name].[Praktikant]
     where age > 23
```

You can use this query to get table columns list to check:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Praktikant'
```